# Lutris Ubuntu 18.04 Overwatch error

Tags: software-installation, wine

I tried to install Overwatch on Ubuntu 18.04 using lutris and this error occurs and the installation stops.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Please ! I am not able to find any help regarding this and this is the installer script for Overwatch on lutris released 7 hours ago:

https://lutris.net/games/overwatch/

https://lutris.net/api/installers/overwatch-dxvk-september-25th-?format=json

Log error showing:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Comment: This isn't really the best place to ask for support on lutris. Have you perhaps tried to contact whomever made the script about the error?

Comment: Hello. For terminal output (to get help here or elsewhere), it's best to copy and paste the terminal output into your question rather than using a screenshot. This makes it much easier to read and has other benefits, like people being able to search for an error message in Google and find your post.

Comment: As for the terminal output above, it's saying that a compressed file (probably with a `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` file extension) is too short. Your download might have gotten cut off, so a redownload might be in order.

Comment: I have tried re downloading it 3 times and the script says its "Gold". I installed all the dependencies mentioned at battle net, DXVK using lutris wiki.

Comment: The script itself might be doing some downloading of its own and might have cached a download that got cut off, and so now that it's cached, it thinks it doesn't need to redownload it. Since it's released only seven hours ago, it might also be buggy. Can you please provide a link to the script by editing your question?

Comment: Here are the links of the script and the main page

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Vulkan or Overwatch, so I can't debug the problem. I'd recommend trying on [the Lutris forums](https://forums.lutris.net/) as well as here. Make sure to: let them know exactly what steps you took to get to the point that you did, let them know what that window says it's downloading, and make sure to copy and paste the output in the terminal there into your forum post.

Comment: Thanks i did post on lutris forums.. i will give updates here too.

Comment: If you do find a solution, you're welcome to add an answer below, just make sure to include a link to where you found the solution if you found it somewhere else and the details here in case the link dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually dont find the solution to the problem but instead of installing Overwatch from lutris i installed battlenet from lutris and install overwatch from there

https://lutris.net/games/battlenet/

The gold DOX version worked like a charm its capable of running all blizard games and has configured DXVK already so no settings needed just some dependecies.Vulkan expirience out of the box.[image]